# SQS subscribing to SNS: How to specify multiple TopicArns in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

A different team has created several SNS topics to work around the SNS quotas. The ARNs are

```
arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:xxxx:SomeTopic.fifo
arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:xxxx:SomeTopic1.fifo
arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:xxxx:SomeTopic2.fifo
...
arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:xxxx:SomeTopicN.fifo
```

I am trying to subscribe an SQS to these topics. My CloudFormation looks like below, with lots of duplication:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters"               : {
        "SomeTopicArn" : {
            "Type" : "String",
            "Default" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:xxxx:SomeTopic.fifo"
        },
        "SomeTopicArn1" : {
            "Type" : "String",
            "Default" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:xxxx:SomeTopic1.fifo"
        }
    },
    "Resources"                : {
        "SomeQueue" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::SQS::Queue",
            "Properties" : {
                "QueueName" : "SomeQueue.fifo",
                "FifoQueue"                     : "true"
            }
        },
        "SubscribeSomeQueueSqsToSomeTopic" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
            "Properties" : {
                "Protocol" : "sqs",
                "Endpoint" : {
                    "Fn::GetAtt" : [
                        "SomeQueue",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "TopicArn" : {
                    "Ref" : "SomeTopicArn"
                }
            }
        },
        "SubscribeSomeQueueSqsToSomeTopic1" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
          "Properties" : {
            "Protocol" : "sqs",
            "Endpoint" : {
              "Fn::GetAtt" : [
                "SomeQueue",
                "Arn"
              ]
            },
            "TopicArn" : {
              "Ref" : "SomeTopicArn1"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I specify multiple TopicArns in one "AWS::SNS::Subscription" to avoid duplication.

I tried using wild cards in the parameters

```
"Parameters"               : {
        "SomeTopicArn" : {
            "Type" : "String",
            "Default" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:xxxx:SomeTopic*.fifo"
        },
```

but it errors out as invalid ARN.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Comment: @Marcin, I looked up a few samples for template macro but cannot get my head wrapped around it. Would you scribble an example for the above cloud formation script? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest trying wring one yourself, and then making a question with the code and details of issues. Alternatively, you can leave CloudFormation to more "normal" IaC tool, such as Terraform. It would be trivial in TF to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way unless you are going to develop your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or [template macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) for that.